# JQuery not interacting with his target when the target is put in a php echo function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having some troubles implementing a login/user system into my website.
Here is the one i'm dealing with for now :

My menu is structured like this :

ftp / projects / contact / "tools icon" / "login or logout icon"

I have created a login window which JQuery is supposed to pop when i click on the login icon. No problem with that when i don't implement any php in it.
But I want the "login icon" to turn into a "logout icon" with obviously differents actions when clicked on it when the user is logged in.

So i came up with this code, which doesn't work well (it is part of my header.php :

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/style/script/menu.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div id="menu">
<a href="/ftp/index.php"><span class="menu_txt" id="current_ftp">ftp</span></a>
<a href="/projects/index.php"><span class="menu_txt" id="current_projects">projects</span></a>
<a href="/contact/index.php"><span class="menu_txt" id="current_contact">contact</span></a>
<span class="menu_img" id="menu_panel"><a href="#"><img src="/style/img/icon_panel.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="" 
name="icon_panel" onmouseover="icon_panel.src='/style/img/icon_panel_hover.jpg'" onmouseout="icon_panel.src='/style/img/icon_panel.jpg'" /></a></span>
<?php if( isset($_SESSION['auth']) ) {
    echo '<span class="menu_img" id="menu_logout"><a href="/ftp/deconnexion.php" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to logout ?\')"><img src="/style/img/logout.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt=""
name="logout" onmouseover="logout.src=\'/style/img/logout_hover.jpg\'" onmouseout="logout.src=\'/style/img/logout.jpg\'" /></a></span>';
}
    else {
        echo '<span class="menu_img" id="menu_login"><a href=""><img src="/style/img/login.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt=""
name="login" onmouseover="login.src=\'/style/img/login_hover.jpg\'" onmouseout="login.src=\'/style/img/login.jpg\'" /></a></span>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

I basically made a condition : if user is logged in -> echo "logout icon/options"
and if user logged out -> echo "login icon/options"

What happens is that the code works and shows me the right icon regarding if i'm logged in or not, but my JQuery doesn't seem to run anymore with the php in here.
It is supposed to be triggered when i click on the login icon but nohting happens.

Here is the script (whole js file) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            // début de la fonction d'affichage de l'élément login
  $('.login_bubble')
  .hide()
  .click(function(event) {
    // Stops click event from bubbling to document (point #2)
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#menu_login').click(function(event){
    // Stops click event from bubbling to document (point #1)
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Toggle visibility (point #1)
    $('.login_bubble').toggle(200);
    $('.panel_bubble').hide(200);
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    // Hide bubble if visible (point #3)
    // Will listen to click events from all other elements
    // ... except for `#menu_login` because we have
    // ... prevent the click event from bubbling up
    $('.login_bubble').filter(':visible').hide(200);
  });
  $('.login_bubble').css('visibility','visible');  // Switch login_bubble to : visible

            // début de la fonction d'affichage de l'élément panel
      $('.panel_bubble')
  .hide()
  .click(function(event) {
    // Stops click event from bubbling to document (point #2)
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#menu_panel').click(function(event){
    // Stops click event from bubbling to document (point #1)
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Toggle visibility (point #1)
    $('.panel_bubble').toggle(200);
    $('.login_bubble').hide(200);
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    // Hide bubble if visible (point #3)
    // Will listen to click events from all other elements
    // ... except for `#menu_login` because we have
    // ... prevent the click event from bubbling up
    $('.panel_bubble').filter(':visible').hide(200);
  });
  $('.panel_bubble').css('visibility','visible');  // Switch login_bubble to : visible

$( "#password" ).focusin(function() {   // début de la fonction d'opacité des éléments mdp_icon et identifiant_icon
  $( this ).find( ".password_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 200);
});

$( "#password" ).focusout(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".password_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 300);
});

$( "#username" ).focusin(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".username_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 200);
});

$( "#username" ).focusout(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".username_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 300);
});

$(".login").submit(function(){      // début de la fonction d'opacité de l'élément de feedback
  $(this).find(".submit i").removeAttr('class').addClass("fa fa-check").css({"color":"#fff"});
  $(".submit").css({"background":"#2ecc71", "border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  $(".feedback").show().animate({"opacity":"1", "bottom":"-80px"}, 400);
  $("input").css({"border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  return false;
});
})
```

I tried changing $(document).ready for $(window).load but it didn't work neither.

Thanks a lot for trying to help me out with this !

Comment: Did you debug and see where it is failing? Does it see the element when you attach the events? Does it go into the methods?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, being a rookie i have no idea what a debug is, so i'll find this out and update my post, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Not that it solves the problem, but don't use inline strings like that to do html it is hard to maintain, either use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax or [alternate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Answer (score 0):

First, there was a missing colon, but I'm hoping this was a typo. Basically, what I did was wrap your functions in a function myLoginFunction(), then called it from within a timeout that waits 500ms after the page is done loading. If your issue was with timing, this should solve it. It has definitely solved many issues on my Wordpress websites.

If it does work, please try reducing the 500, to 50 or something smaller than 500 to conserve resources.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        myLoginFunction();
    },500);
});
function myLoginFunction(){
    // début de la fonction d'affichage de l'élément login
  $('.login_bubble')
  .hide()
  .click(function(event) {
    // Stops click event from bubbling to document (point #2)
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#menu_login').click(function(event){
    // Stops click event from bubbling to document (point #1)
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Toggle visibility (point #1)
    $('.login_bubble').toggle(200);
    $('.panel_bubble').hide(200);
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    // Hide bubble if visible (point #3)
    // Will listen to click events from all other elements
    // ... except for `#menu_login` because we have
    // ... prevent the click event from bubbling up
    $('.login_bubble').filter(':visible').hide(200);
  });
  $('.login_bubble').css('visibility','visible');  // Switch login_bubble to : visible

            // début de la fonction d'affichage de l'élément panel
      $('.panel_bubble')
  .hide()
  .click(function(event) {
    // Stops click event from bubbling to document (point #2)
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#menu_panel').click(function(event){
    // Stops click event from bubbling to document (point #1)
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Toggle visibility (point #1)
    $('.panel_bubble').toggle(200);
    $('.login_bubble').hide(200);
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    // Hide bubble if visible (point #3)
    // Will listen to click events from all other elements
    // ... except for `#menu_login` because we have
    // ... prevent the click event from bubbling up
    $('.panel_bubble').filter(':visible').hide(200);
  });
  $('.panel_bubble').css('visibility','visible');  // Switch login_bubble to : visible

$( "#password" ).focusin(function() {   // début de la fonction d'opacité des éléments mdp_icon et identifiant_icon
  $( this ).find( ".password_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 200);
});

$( "#password" ).focusout(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".password_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 300);
});

$( "#username" ).focusin(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".username_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 200);
});

$( "#username" ).focusout(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".username_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 300);
});

$(".login").submit(function(){      // début de la fonction d'opacité de l'élément de feedback
  $(this).find(".submit i").removeAttr('class').addClass("fa fa-check").css({"color":"#fff"});
  $(".submit").css({"background":"#2ecc71", "border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  $(".feedback").show().animate({"opacity":"1", "bottom":"-80px"}, 400);
  $("input").css({"border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  return false;
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ! Just tried it and also different values but it didn't work out :/ I'm starting to think the problem comes from the way i echo'd my code but i can't see anything wrong